# How to export mlogit results to excel?

Tags: r, export, export-to-excel

Does exist any package which can help me to export results of multinomial logit to excel for example like a table?

Comment: Why? What can excel do with the output?

Comment: @Edward I need these results in Excel to compare them with other analysis.

Comment: I think the `tidy` function from __broom__ has a multinom method. You can try that.

Comment: You can look into the write_xlsx function from the xlsx package.  You will probably need to set up the table you want to export first.

Answer (score 0):

The broom package does a reasonable job of tidying multinomial output.

```
library(broom)
library(nnet)

fit.gear <- multinom(gear ~ mpg + factor(am), data = mtcars)
summary(fit.gear)
```

---

```
Call:
multinom(formula = gear ~ mpg + factor(am), data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       mpg factor(am)1
4   -11.15154 0.5249369    11.90045
5   -18.39374 0.3662580    22.44211

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept)       mpg factor(am)1
4    5.317047 0.2680456   66.895845
5   67.931319 0.2924021    2.169944

Residual Deviance: 28.03075 
AIC: 40.03075
```

---

```
tidy(fit.gear)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  y.level term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 4       (Intercept)  1.44e-5     5.32     -2.10  3.60e- 2
2 4       mpg          1.69e+0     0.268     1.96  5.02e- 2
3 4       factor(am)1  1.47e+5    66.9       0.178 8.59e- 1
4 5       (Intercept)  1.03e-8    67.9      -0.271 7.87e- 1
5 5       mpg          1.44e+0     0.292     1.25  2.10e- 1
6 5       factor(am)1  5.58e+9     2.17     10.3   4.54e-25
```

---

Then use the openxlsx package to send that to Excel.

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(file="E:/.../fitgear.xlsx", tidy(fit.gear))
```

---

(Note that the `tidy` function exponentiates the coefficients by default, although the help page incorrectly says the default is FALSE). So these are relative risk ratios, which is why they don't match the output of `summary`. And if you want confidence intervals, you have to ask for them.)